# Returning a copy of class

Tags: java, oop, linked-list, return

Let's say I have a linked list.

```
class LinkedList {
...
    private Node head;
    private int length;

    private class Node {
        Element element;
        Node next;
    }

    public LinkedList tail() { }
}
```

How would I implement `tail` so that:

1. It returns the `LinkedList`, without the `Head` element.
2. Any changes made to the original `LinkedList` is reflected upon what `tail` returns

Things I've tried:

```
  // This fails because it creates a new LinkedList, and modifying 'this' won't affect the new LinkedList.
  public LinkedList tail() {
    LinkedList temp = new LinkedList();
    temp.head = this.head.next;
    temp.length = this.length - 1;
    return temp;
  }

  // This fails because it modifies the original LinkedList.
  public LinkedList tail() {
    LinkedList temp = this;
    temp.head = this.head.next;
    temp.length = this.length - 1;
    return temp;
  }
```

Basically, I need `tail` to point at the `head.next`.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to use a cons list rather than a linked list.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, huh?

Comment: A linked list is unsuited for what you ask, as you _have_ to return a `new` instance of your class with the different `head` element - your first approach. A cons list is a persistent data structure (from functional programming) that is exactly designed for this use case.

Comment: Could you explain further why your two solutions failed? You say that the first fails because modifying 'this' (i.e. the original LinkedList) does not effect the returned list. You say that the second fails because modifying the original LinkedList (i.e. 'this') does effect the returned list. I can see why the second clearly doesn't work but I'm still not sure why the first fails?

Comment: Let's say I have:  `list1 = new LinkedList();` and `list2 = list1.tail()`. Adding an element to the end of `list1` should affect `list2`. But adding an element to the front of `list1` should NOT affect `list2`.

Comment: Because `list2` is just a pointer to the next element in `list1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of LinkedList which wraps the original:

```
class TailList extends LinkedList {
  LinkedList list;
  TailList(LinkedList list) { this.list=list;}
  Node head() { return list.head().next; }
  int length() { return list.length()-1;}
}
```

Of course you have to encapsulate the fields in LinkedList first. I would actually turn LinkedList into an interface, turn your current LinkedList into **LinkedListImpl implements LinkedList** and add the TailList as described above.

```
class LinkedListImpl implements LinkedList{
  ...
  LinkedList tail(){ return new TailList(this); }
  ...
}
```

Btw. I recommend considering immutable data structures...

Comment: Hi, so how would this work with the `tail` function? Would I return a `TailList` or a `LinkedList`? And inside `tail`: Do I create a `new TailList(this)`? Is `TailList` a class of its own, or does it belong inside `LinkedList`?

Comment: Updated answer. I would keep the TailList as private inner class of the linked list implementation.